# Prob. 7, Sec. 16 , in Munkres' TOPOLOGY, 2nd ed.: Is every proper convex subset of a totally ordered set necessarily an interval or a ray?

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be an ordered set. If $Y$ is a proper subset of $X$ that is convex in $X$, does it follow that $Y$ is an interval or a ray in $X$?

My answer:

The set $Y$ could be either empty or a singleton set (i.e. a degenerate interval) unless it is an interval or a ray in $X$; so the answer to the question above is "no."

Am I right?

Comment: But maybe a singleton is considered to be an interval, and the empty set is excluded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is false.  Consider the set $\{x\in\Bbb Q: -\sqrt 2<x<\sqrt 2\}$.  This set is clearly convex, but is is not an interval or a ray in $\Bbb Q$.

Comment: this set is not convex in $\mathbb{R]$; it contains, for example, both $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$ and $-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$ but not $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{4}$ although $-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} < \frac{\sqrt{2}}{4} < \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$.

Comment: It is not convex in $\Bbb R$, but it is convex in $\Bbb Q$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the set $(-\infty,0)\cup(0,\infty)$ in the order induced by the reals. Both components are not rays or intervals.

Comment: the set you've given is clearly not convex, for it contains, for example, both $1$ and $-1$ but not $0$.

Comment: The components $(-\infty,0)$ and $(0,\infty)$ are. That's the point.